# How to create Junit for the code that uses envers?

Tags: java, jpa, junit, ehcache, hibernate-envers

I am to write a JUnit to check that version is being maintained or not(on an event). Here is what I did using JUnit:

```
@Test
Public void testAudit() {
    try {
        //create Dao code
        dao.save();  //This will create entry in  AUD- and REVINFO-tables perfectly
        SomeObject obj = SomeHelper.getAuditData(dao));
        /*Method to be tested which generates audit message using envers i.e(dao created)*/
        //Some logic to check if output is as expected  
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        Assert.fail();
    }
    finally {
        dao.delete();  //delete the data saved by JUnit (Problem starts here )
    }
}
```

Calling the delete for dao would cause

> UnsupportedOperationException: Can't write to a readonly object

I use Ehcache for caching. I googled for the problem and came to know that it might be because of `CacheConcurrencyStrategy` wrongly set for domain object which I want to delete. I checked.

For domain object there was no `CacheConcurrencyStrategy`. But nested object had `CacheConcurrencyStrategy` set as `READ_WRITE` (This might be real culprit).

But I don't want to change existing domain and existing code. Is it any way to bypass `CacheConcurrencyStrategy` for JUnit? If not, is there any possible way out without changing the existing code?

Comment: You should show us where the exception is thrown, what does delete do? Why ch is your stack trace?

Comment: Do you try to delete the Envers entries as well? Maybe just try to empty the revisions table if you want audit data deleted.

Answer (score 2):

The ENVERs data is written post the transactions commit, so your code will never access the audit record, because one does not exist yet. If you want to test ENVERs, you need to manage the transactions yourself. Here is an example;

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    // Envers audit information is written via post-event listeners and therefore the transaction needs to be
    // committed.
    PlatformTransactionManager txMgr = applicationContext.getBean(PlatformTransactionManager.class);
    TransactionStatus status = txMgr.getTransaction(new DefaultTransactionDefinition(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW));
    Account account = accountDAO.getByUsername(UPDATE);
    if (account != null) {
        accountDAO.delete(account);
    }

    account = createAccount();
    account.setUsername(INITIAL);
    accountDAO.update(account);
    txMgr.commit(status);

    status = txMgr.getTransaction(new DefaultTransactionDefinition(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW));
    account.setUsername(UPDATE);
    accountDAO.update(account);
    txMgr.commit(status);

}
```

Then in your test, you can query out the audit information anyway you want (raw SQL, via the AuditReader, etc).